# postgresql 9.3 with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS throw 's ERROR: invalid page in block 105 of relation base/16385/17407

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, corruption

This is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with postgresql 9.3 in production, Now i got this below error's in log.

```
# tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
2015-01-08 14:10:16 IST CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "lms_production.pg_toast.pg_toast_17005"
2015-01-08 14:10:29 IST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2015-01-08 14:11:10 IST ERROR:  invalid page in block 105 of relation base/16385/17407
2015-01-08 14:11:10 IST STATEMENT:  select count(*) from report_snapshots;
2015-01-08 14:11:16 IST ERROR:  invalid page in block 632 of relation base/16385/17010
2015-01-08 14:11:16 IST CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "lms_production.pg_toast.pg_toast_17005"
2015-01-08 14:11:29 IST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2015-01-08 14:12:16 IST ERROR:  invalid page in block 632 of relation base/16385/17010
2015-01-08 14:12:16 IST CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "lms_production.pg_toast.pg_toast_17005"
2015-01-08 14:12:29 IST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2015-01-08 14:13:16 IST ERROR:  invalid page in block 632 of relation base/16385/17010
2015-01-08 14:13:16 IST CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "lms_production.pg_toast.pg_toast_17005"
2015-01-08 14:13:29 IST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

While checking for error reports in postgres it shows the count fine.

```
# select count(*) from error_reports;

 count 
-------
  5345
(1 row)
```

While checking for report_snapshots it's throwing the above error.

```
# select count(*) from report_snapshots;

ERROR:  invalid page in block 105 of relation base/16385/17407
```

While googling found that someone says it's disk problem but here we use dedicated server and this database running machine is one of the virtual machine for production. Disk have enough space and nothing issue with disk, Other virtual machine running in host are working without any issue's. Any one there to fix this issue ?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.3.what? `SELECT version()` please. Have there been any failovers / promotions of this node using streaming replication?

Comment: Very good only you ppls spending time to find that not to resolve the issue

Comment: This is not a cluster s single node

Comment: Version was Psql (9.3.5)

Comment: OK, and is it running, or has it ever run, with `fsync = off`? What's the underlying storage system - disks, controller, filesystem, any logical volume management, etc.

Comment: Oh no idea about that all, We are from small production scale. we use dedicated server and installed with promox virtualization in that we have this virtual machine. it's filesystem. Yes database still running but in canvas software some features are not working properly due to this issue.

Comment: I don't really understand the last comment, could you elaborate in an edit to your question? Please cover all the bases, but *in particular* it's crucial to know if your PostgreSQl install has `fsync` set to `off` or has had so in the past. Also if there have been any restarts/crashes. Issues with unflushed writes due to improper write ordering are by far the most common cause of this sort of issue. (It might be informative to run the `pg_test_fsync` program bundled with PostgreSQL and see what its output is, too.)

Comment: Note that you can, in an absolute emergency, set `zero_damaged_pages`. However *this will destroy data unrecoverably and permanently* and *may make the situation much worse*. Do not do it until you have read, understood, and followed the instructions at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Comment: Be sure to have a good backup around. Then reread Craig's link above twice and put the physical files somewhere safe. But if you're lucky, corruption might be just affecting indexes. The only way to know is look at the execution plan, see if any are being used and if that's the case, rebuild them.